# Classes abstratas em Python

Tags: python, classes-abstratas

O método `__subclasscheck__` deve ser definido a nível de metaclasse, já o método `__subclasshook__` pode ser definido como um método de classe desde que a classe possua como metaclasse `ABC` (ou uma de suas derivadas).
Minha dúvida é quando criamos uma abstração implementando `ABCMeta` como metaclasse, podemos fazer uso do decorador `@abstractmethod` que define que o método deve ser sobrescrito na classe derivada, mas vi em muitos códigos fazerem o uso desses métodos (`__subclasscheck__`, `__subclasshook__`) para fazer a validação seja da implementação dos métodos que devem ser sobrescritos ou alterar o comportamento do método `issubclass()`. Alguém poderia me dizer um caso de uso onde deva-se implementar esses métodos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Prover casos de uso" para esse tipo de feature é bem complicado - tratam-se de funcionalidades colocadas no core da linguagem para permitir manipualção e customização avançada de hierarquia de classes -  o tipo de coisas que vai precisar ser feito uma vez, por exemplo, num ORM, ou próximo as classes-base de um projeto com uma hierarquia grande de classes e especificidades muito bem definidas.

A maior parte dos projetos - mesmo os grandes, vai usar frameworks que já vão ter esse tipo de funcionalidade definida (seja o Django, seja algum outro usando SQLAlchemy): ou seja - é bem *dificil*  imaginar um caso de uso para essas funcionalidades. Um caso de uso concreto e simples mais díficil ainda.

Basicamente, o `__subclasscheck__` em si, junto com o `__instancecheck__` são funcionalidades da linguagem em si. Não seria falso dizer que foram introduzidas na linguagem justamente para permitir que o módulo ABC (Abstract base Classes) fosse criado com as funcionalidades que tem hoje.

Basicamente eles permitem que ao definir uma metaclasse você possa customizar e dizer que alguma outra classe, ou objeto de uma classe não relacionado com as classes da sua hierarquia (isso é, as classes definidas com a sua metaclasse), são instâncias das mesmas - mesmo que isso nunca tenha sido a intenção de quem escreveu a classe original.

Então - para dar um exemplo concreto: Python usa as ABCMeta para definir as classes em collections.ABC - essas sim, podendo ter bastante uso no dia a dia, permitindo a implementação rápida e simples de sequências e mappings pelo usuário (mesmo assim, tem mais uso em uma biblioteca intermediária que num projeto final). Mas basicamente, ao desenhar a `collections.abc.MutableSequence` seria interessante que se alguém perguntasse se uma `list` de Python é uma `MutableSequence` a resposta fosse True: ou seja, uma lista tem sim a interface de uma MutableSequence. E é para isso que esses mecanismos são usados na biblioteca padrão do Python:  para dizer que os tipos de dados nativos do Python - set, frozenset, list, tuple, string, dict são "subclasses" das classes abstratas correspondentes:

```
In [39]: issubclass(dict, collections.abc.MutableMapping)
Out[39]: True
```

O mesmo mecanismo é usado na classe `typing` da stdlib, que está lá para prover mecanismos de type-hinting para código moderno:

```
In [41]: issubclass(list, typing.MutableSequence)
Out[41]: True
```

(a MutableSequence do módulo typing no entanto, existe  para indicar que naquele ponto qualquer tipo que tenha a interface de uma "Sequência mutável" vai ser aceito - enquanto que collections.abc.MutableSequence por outro lado existe para ser uma classe base para implementações pelo usuário de MutableSequences escrevendo-se o mínimo de código possível. São coisas diferentes)

Já - ao contrário do `__subclasscheck__`, que vai na metaclasse e é uma feature *da linguagem*, o `__subclasshook__` é definido apenas pelo módulo abc e sua metaclasse ABCMeta - basicamente, o `__subclasscheck__` de `abc.ABCMeta` faz a chamada ao `__subclashook__`. Ou seja - o próprio mecanismo do `__subclasshook__` é um exemplo do que pode ser feito com o `__subclasscheck__`: permitir que a própria classe tenha um método para dizer se uma outra classe é uma subclasse dela mesma (sem precisar escrever código diferente na metaclasse para cada classe que você quiser testar esse tipo de coisa)

## Resumindo:

Em 98% dos casos você não vai precisar de nenhuma dessas funcionalidades.
No caso de você estar definindo uma hierarquia de classes que faça uso de calsses abstratas, você pode, nas classes base da sua hierarquia, usar o `__subclashook__` para dizer qual vai ser a resposta das chamadas embutidas do Python `issubclass` e `isinstance` para objetos (e classes) fora da sua hierarquia.  (ou cruzando ramos da sua hierarquia). Esses são os "2%" restantes.

Na biblioteca padrão esse mecanismo é usado para dizer que os tipos nativos como dict, list, etc...são subclasses de "MutableMapping", "MutableSequence"... conforme apropriado.